# How to cover Catch exception in a test class

Tags: code-coverage, exception, schedulebatch

Below is my code
Apex class

```
    global class CasinoFeeReminderScheduler implements Schedulable{
global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    try{
        CasinoFeeReminderEmailBatch batch = new CasinoFeeReminderEmailBatch();
        database.executeBatch(batch,50);
    }
    Catch(Exception e){
        ErrorLogger.logGeneralException(e, UserInfo.getUserId(), 'CasinoFeeReminderScheduler', Label.Str_execute_batch_event, 'Schedulable', 'CasinoFeeReminderScheduler', label.Str_Low);
    }
}  }
```

Test class:

```
    @isTest
    private class OH_CasinoFeeReminderSchedulerTest {

public static testMethod void testschedule(){
    test.startTest();
    OH_CasinoFeeReminderScheduler cas = new OH_CasinoFeeReminderScheduler ();
    String sch = '0 0 2 1 1/1 ? *';
    system.schedule('Testing Compliance Documentation Due Date', sch, cas);
    cas.execute(null);
    test.stopTest();
}}
```

How can I cover the Catch (Exception e) lines? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not have a _specific_ exception that you _know_ that code can throw, you should not be writing an exception handler. What exception will those two lines throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from any possible exceptions your `CasinoFeeReminderEmailBatch` might throw, there's no possible exception here that you can catch (the only possible exceptions would be LimitException, which cannot be caught). As such, there's no need for the try-catch block unless you have some specific situation in your constructor where an exception might be thrown. In addition, because there's no possible exception that can be thrown, the catch block cannot be covered.